# bibtex does not work in beamer

Tags: beamer, bibtex, natbib

I am preparing a simple presentation and would like to select some of the references in my bibtex file. I tried to do it as I do in a .tex file but it gave me '?'.

I am using the package bib at the beginning as

```
\usepackage{natbib}
```

I am doing the citations at the body of my slides such as `\citep{xxx}`

Then at the end, I add the commands

```
\begin{frame}{References}
\bibliography{mybib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\end{frame}
```

Do you have any idea why it does not work?

Comment: Did you run the usual sequence LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864)? Do you get any error messages when you run BibTeX (check the `.blg` file)? Are there any errors or warnings on the LaTeX run (apart from the ones mentioning missing citations and an empty bibliography on the first run)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you run the usual compiling chain: `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`?

Comment: Thanks both. It was pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX in default. I just changed the order and it worked.